# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, nodejs, xampp

Firstly i was a windows programmer and recently switched to linux (*ubuntu 18.04* distro) .
On Windows my code was working fine but on linux it started showing the error.`Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306`

my connection code :

```
import { createConnection } from 'mysql';

export default createConnection({
host: 'localhost',
user: 'root',
password: '',
database: 'rent_compair',
});
```

server.js:

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import admin from './routes/admin';
import db from './config/mysql';

const app = express();

db.connect((err) => {
if (err) throw err;

console.log('Db Connected!');
});

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.use('/', admin);
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, console.log('Server Connected!'));
```

xampp started with sudo privileges:
[xampp server snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dateW.png)

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that you cannot connect to MySQL with the `root` account anymore. This rule was changed — and enforced — within MySQL starting a few years ago. While it is possible to update the configuration to allow it, it is strongly discouraged *even for development environments*.

Instead, if you need the application to have complete control over a database, you can create an account and give it full control like this:

```
CREATE USER 'app_name'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'superSecretPassword!123';
GRANT ALL ON `database`.* TO 'app_name'@'localhost';
```

In the event you want the application to have even more control, you can allow it access to everything, including the ability to create new accounts, like this:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'app_name'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```